# Trim email list into domain list

Tags: php, explode, trim

The function below is part of a script to trim email list from a file into domain list and removes duplicates.

```
/* define a function that can accept a list of email addresses */
function getUniqueDomains($list) {
    // iterate over list, split addresses and add domain part to another array
    $domains = array();
    foreach ($list as $l) {
        $arr = explode("@", $l);
        $domains[] = trim($arr[1]);
    }

    // remove duplicates and return
    return array_unique($domains);
}
```

What does `$domains[] = trim($arr[1]);` mean? Specifically the `$arr[1]`. What does `[1]` mean in this context? How come variable `$arr` becomes an array variable?

Comment: Yes, explode will separate the strings into arrays by @ (in this case). So for example: test@testing.com try@trying.com become test(array0) testing.com(array1) try(array2) trying.com(array3). Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

1 is the index of the array.

Let's say you have an email address: email@gmail.com. 
`explode` will split the string into an array using the specified character as the separator.

In this case `$arr = explode("@", $l);` will split the email using the "@" character and store the array in $arr.

`$arr = explode("@", "email@gmail.com");` will result in the following array:

```
$arr[0] = "email"
$arr[1] = "gmail.com"
```

`$domains[] = trim($arr[1]);` stores the domain ($arr[1]) in the domains array

Answer (score 0):

What [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) does is it returns an **array**, where each part of the array is text that has been split by the delimiter, in this case `@`.

What [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) does is it strips a string from the following characters:

- `' '` An ordinary space.
- `'\t'` A tab.
- `'\n'` A new line.
- `'\r'` A carriage return.
- `'\0'` The ***NUL***-byte
- `'\x0b'` A vertical tab.

---

**Step 1:** You give `getUniqueDomains($list)` a list.

**Step 2:** For each email, it explodes the email with the `@` delimeter.

This means that if I gave the email `iteachyou@stackoverflow.phpstuff`, `$arr` would become an array containing `iteachyou` as `[0]` and `stackoverflow.phpstuff` as `[1]`.

In this case `[0]` or `[1]` is the index in the array. If the array had 23 items, then I could say `$array[22]` to get the last item. Array indexes usually start with 0 for the first item, 1 for the second, etc.

**Step 3:** It trims the URL, which currently is located at `$arr[1]`. This is for cleanup. It also adds the URL to the `$domains` array.

**Step 4:** It checks for duplicates. I am assuming that there is actual code that checks for duplicates, and not just a comment.

**Step 5:** `return` the result.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, it starts making sense to me. What if I have numbers of email list, not only one email. Will $arr[3], $arr[5], or so...produce the same result?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... could you elaborate?